# dropzone.js remove click to upload

Tags: javascript

I am using the `dropzone.js` plugin for a project. I'm wondering if there is a way to stop the `click` event (where you can select a file) but keep the drag and drop function.

The drag and drop are on our entire page and the click is getting annoying when you are just selecting text.

I have tried

```
$('.dropzone')[0].removeEventListener('click', myDropzone.listeners[1].events.click);
```

and

```
$(".dz-hidden-input").prop("disabled",true);
```

but these disable the drag and drop which I still need to work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the [**`clickable`**](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#config-clickable) option to `false` when initializing the Dropzone. According to the DOCS

> If true, the dropzone element itself will be clickable, if false
>   nothing will be clickable.
>
> You can also pass an HTML element, a CSS selector (for multiple
>   elements) or an array of those. In that case, all of those elements
>   will trigger an upload when clicked.

See demo below

```js
// Dropzone class:
$("div#myDZ").dropzone({
  url: "/file/post",
  clickable: false
});
```

```css
#myDZ {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 2px inset #c8c8c8;
  font-family: Calibri;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dropzone/5.4.0/min/dropzone.min.js"></script>

<div id="myDZ">
  Drag / Drop your files here . Click is <kbd>DISABLED</kbd> and wont work
</div>
```